# Hive error with the command show tables

Tags: hive

I am using Apache-Hadoop and Hive as a setup. The hive do get connected with the Hadoop,tables are also created. But with the command show tables this exception occurs:`Failed with the exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException:Input Pattern file:/tmp/${hduser}/034cbea3-2b60-49f5-8284-d6fba957dda3/hive_2015-06-18_05-10-04_183_5811447541305606525-1/-local-10000 matches 0 files`

What is the exception and how should i solve it. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

So please check out the file: `vim $HIVE_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml`, and you should check the `<name>system:user.name`, it's value should be `hduser` not `${hduser}`.

please take the right/correct name for the user.

Comment: I guess, user referring ${hduser} as dynamic value, if not agree with you.